# Почему-то не показываются маленькие и большие иконки на сайте

Tags: html, css

Почему-то не показываются маленькие иконки на сайте[image: Первая картинка]

[image: Вторая, с боков не двух иконок и посередине]

**Пример кода:**  class="ion-ios-cart"

**Пример кода:** i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"

**Объясните, почему?**

Answer (score 1):

шрифт не подключил нужный. Или адрес указан не верно